# finding the minimum value of multiple variables by group

Tags: r, plyr

I would like to find the minimum value of a variable (time) that several other variables are equal to 1 (or any other value).  Basically my application is finding the first year that x ==1, for several x.  I know how to find this for one x but would like to avoid generating multiple reduced data frames of minima, then merging these together.  Is there an efficient way to do this?  Here is my example data and solution for one variable.

```
d <- data.frame(cat = c(rep("A",10), rep("B",10)),
                time = c(1:10),
                var1 = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                var2 = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1))

ddply(d[d$var1==1,], .(cat), summarise,
      start= min(time))
```

Comment: Could you please provide the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

How about this using `dplyr`

```
d %>% 
   group_by(cat) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(contains("var")), funs(time[which(. == 1)[1]]))
```

Which gives

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#   cat    var1  var2
#   <fct> <int> <int>
# 1 A         4     5
# 2 B         7     8
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R` to get the minimum 'time' among all the columns of 'var' grouped by 'cat'

```
sapply(split(d[-1], d$cat), function(x)
            x$time[min(which(x[-1] ==1, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1])])
#A B 
#4 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you are expecting?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- d %>% 
group_by(cat, var1, var2) %>% 
summarise(start = min(time)) %>% 
filter()
```

I have left a blank `filter` argument that you can use to specify any filter condition you want (say `var1 == 1` or `cat == "A"`)